# Connection per user

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I'm using the code below, and what I want to do is use the same connection for the user throughout the time they are logged in.  Now my understanding of using is it disposes of the connection, but what I really want to do is when a user logs in, create a connection and have them use that specific connection.

Below is a code I know works for setting a connection in C#, and I would apply [ThreadStatic] attribute to `public static MySqlConnection ATCrawlerConnection`, but how do you accomplish the similar functionality in aspx, basically creating a connection per user and then accessing and limiting that connection for that user?

In C# I would use this:

```
MySQLProcessing.MySQLStatic.ATCrawlerConnection MySQLProcessing.MySQLStatic.OpenCon("10.2", 3306, "user", "pw");
```

public static MySqlConnection ATCrawlerConnection { get; set; }

public static MySqlConnection OpenCon(string ServerAddress, int PortAddress, string UserID, string Password)
        {
            MySqlConnection masterOpenCON = new MySqlConnection("server=" + ServerAddress + ";Port=" + PortAddress + ";UID=" + UserID + ";PASSWORD=" + Password);// + ";connectiontimeout=" + ConnectionTimeOut + ";");
            masterOpenCON.Open();
            return masterOpenCON;
        }

`public static DataTable StoreProcedureDTTable(string mysqlQuery, string[] CommandArgs, string queryName)
    {
        lock (_object)
        {
            using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(applicationStringClass.AuthMySQLConnector))
            {

                DataTable DTTableTable = new DataTable();
                try
                {
                    MySqlCommand MySQLCommandFunc = new MySqlCommand(mysqlQuery);
                    MySQLCommandFunc.Connection = cn;
                    MySQLCommandFunc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    foreach (string args in CommandArgs)
                    {
                        string[] splitArgs = args.Split('|');
                        MySQLCommandFunc.Parameters.AddWithValue(splitArgs[0], splitArgs[1]);
                    }
                    MySqlDataAdapter DataDTTables = new MySqlDataAdapter(MySQLCommandFunc);
                    DataTable DataDTTablesDT = new DataTable();
                    DataDTTables.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 240000;
                    DataDTTables.Fill(DataDTTablesDT);
                    DTTableTable = DataDTTablesDT;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
                return DTTableTable;
            }
        }

    }`

Comment: Static will use the same connection for every user, there is a single instance of a static object in the system.  However why do you want this requirement, maintaining a single connection could cause problems when if connections are not returned to the connection pool or transaction locks if you have a high level of concurrency

Comment: your concept goes against microsoft's advices on how to use the connections, and working with connection pools. you can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.100).aspx):
"We strongly recommend that you always close the connection when you are finished using it so that the connection will be returned to the pool"

Comment: @Mike Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should

- Create a connection when you need it, and dispose it as soon as you don't use it
- Keep the same connection string for all connection
- Don't share connection on different thread, otherwise you'll have errors if 2 threads use the connection at the same time. You'll not have this problem with your static method, because you put lock, but if the server load is too heavy a lot of time will be loose by waiting to acquire the lock.

The .NET is already optimized to not open connection each time you create a new connection, it's called "[Connection Pooling](http://aspalliance.com/1099_Understanding_Connection_Pooling_in_NET.all)".
The reason why you should keep the same connection string is because the connection pool use this to "cache" connections. So if you connection string change (i.e. application name) it'll create a new connection.

So don't try to do what's already done, just create a new connection and dispose it asap after you finished your batch of queries.

Comment: Fabske the problem is you create temp tables and they only stay around for the connection, you close it you lose the tmp db

Comment: Yes, it's why it a temp table. If you need to keep it, just create a standard table. Keep in mind that the connection could also be broken due to a network error, so you can't assume that your temp table will always be available...

Answer (score 0):

First, a caveat: You absolutely *should not* be doing what you're asking; it's a really bad idea, especially when applied to a web site. Most database libraries use a connection pooling strategy to reduce resource usage, and keeping connections open longer than needed messes that up. It also leaves you open to leak resources when there's no clear way to know when a connection is finished.

If you insist, though...

Whenever you want to do something in ASP.NET that is "for a given user", you are usually looking for the Session state tracking. The Session object can be used to store arbitrary information that ASP.NET tracks on a per-user basis. ("User" here means a browser with a particular cookie visiting the site.)

Setting up and storing a per-user connection via the Session object is pretty easy, as described in this [Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) page from Microsoft.

The tricky part is knowing when to close it. If your site has some well-defined log in and out strategy, that's a good possibility. But you can't assume that your users will always visit that log-out page. The session state is stored in the worker process's memory, which IIS will recycle (largely to alleviate this exact problem), but that is very non-deterministic. This is one main reason why storing open resources in a session state is discouraged.

Comment: Okay, how could i create and keep a temporary table new user

Answer (score 0):

You cant solve ur problems by breaking the way ASP.NET (or any other technology for that matters) is supposed to be used, by the defnition of the people who built it. IF u want to store temp data for the user (which u didnt mention in ur original post), you can use other strategies, such as  using a physical table in ur DB and using the On_SessionEnd events of ASP.NET to delete all the user-related data, or stroing the temp data in proc memory.

you can actually [store ur session data within the db](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-net-tutorials-asp-provider-session-state.html), and im pretty convinced
neither mysql nor sql server are using temp tables, but rather apply something similar to the technique ive suggested